# Update request.session variable before function ends

Tags: django, session-variables

At a Django server, I have a page with a single button that starts a function.
This function takes a while to complete, and I tried writing updates on the process to a request.session variable with the intent of checking on its contents from a separate page. 
It seems however that request.session variables are not updated until the function they are included in are done. At least the variable does not update until then. 
Am I right, and if so, is there a way to write to request.session variable before the function's completion?

The sessions are set up properly, I can write and read variables with other examples. For now I'll also just make a temporary db record to store the status update info and read it from there, but I'm curious as of this request.session thing - is my guess correct, and is there a way around?

update:

views.py

```
@login_required
def autolink(request):
    result, time = access_check(request, 'super')
    if not result:
        return redirect('index')
    result = f_autolink(request)
    if result is None:
        result = request.session.get('technical', '')
    return render(request, 'autolink.html', {'result': result, })
```

functions.py

```
def f_autolink(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = None
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['technical'] = 'starting the job'
        result = f_kzd_autolink(request)
    else:
        result = None
    return result

def f_kzd_autolink(request):
    homeless = Kzd.objects.filter(payment__isnull=True, returned=False).distinct()
    result = []
    count = homeless.count()
    counter = 0
    request.session['technical'] = 'Starting link job - {c} records to process'.format(c=count)
    for h in homeless:
        counter += 1
        request.session['technical'] = 'Checking record {c1} of {c}'.format(c1=counter, c=count)
/* long code that makes the h in homeless cycle run for about 3 minutes, unrelated to the question */
```

so basically, the view shows request.session.get('technical', ''), but neither function writes to it until they are done (it then writes about processing the last record).

Comment: You should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Post your view and what you tried already. Then it will be much easier to provide an answer.

Comment: @trixn sorry, added info.

Comment: If you have long computations to run, you really want to run them out of band using some async task system like celery, rq etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session is saved on a per-request basis when it was [modified](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) or when the setting `settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` is set to `True` in your settings.

So the simple answer yes, the session is saved by the session middleware when processing the response created by a view. But you could do it manually by calling `request.session.save()` inside your view.

If you have code, that runs very long it would be better to imediately create a response and use tools like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to asynchronously process your task.

And you should consider storing your data into an own database table/ own model if it is not really related to the user session.

Comment: Great, that works. Thanks a lot, I was not able to figure that on my own from the documentation! As to celery and db, yes, I agree. That was really just a quick fix that I need for a separate task, so I just wanted a quick update. Celery definitely would be better, but I didn't learn to use it yet. The tutorial is sitting in the bookmarks bar though, so I hope I will soon.